# Help me to prove related path component and open ball

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $W$ be a open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ be path component of $W$.

Consider $p\in U$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Prove that if $B_r(p)\subset W$ then $B_r(p)\subset U$ where $B_{r}(p)$ is the open ball with center $p$ of radius $r$.

I am not sure how to proceed . Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Have the definition of path-component in front of you, where you can see what it says, and draw a picture. Then look at them both.

Comment: Hint.  Open balls of $R^n$ are path connected.